# Change image size on gmail addon with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to insert three images in my gmail addon, one below the other. The problem is that the images are automatically scaled and are too big, so to see the three at the same time I have to scroll when I would like to see them directly. I haven't seen information to resize an image in the documentation, the closest option I have found is by applying the following crop style on images as gridItems but it does not seem to be the most correct solution because after all I am cropping the image.

```
CardService.newImageCropStyle()
    .setImageCropType(CardService.ImageCropType.RECTANGLE_CUSTOM).setAspectRatio(2)
```

I have also tried with icons but I have not achieved the result I expected.

Comment: How are you adding the images? Have you tried resizing it before with [scaleHeight(ratio) 
 / scaleWidth(ratio)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#scaleheightratio)?

Comment: I'm using newImage() method because im using CardService to build the addon. That method doesnt appear on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image?hl=en) for that class Image

Comment: Can you share the full code you are using in order to try it? You are right those methods do not seem to be applicable to the Card images but could be done using the [Grid](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/grid?hl=en) in order to define the space those images have to expand to.